# Android : Recorded message as input in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, audio-recording

I am working on a project where i  want a recorded  audio message as input in `edittext` like `whatsapp` . Please help.

Comment: "Please help" - with what exactly? What have you already tried? What are you struggling with?

Comment: do you wanna translate audio to text ?? or send the audio ??

Comment: just want to send the audio msg

Comment: i have tried this thing https://github.com/sarathnk/Audio, but i want audio file in edittext like whatsapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically pressing the audio icon in WhatsApp then showing recording audio is part of view animation.Where there are two views one is EditText and other Audio capturing View.

For  audio capturing, you will have to use MediaRecorder class of Andriod. 
Here is the link how to capture Audio in Android:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

Hope this will give you some idea to resolve this problem.